# javascript checking for blank for phonenumber and address

Tags: javascript, html

Please help me, I'm stuck.

Why doesn't the JavaScript below work? The script is checking if phone number and address is empty, but when the phone number and address field is entered, the alert still pops out.

```js
const order = document.getElementById("orderInput");
const main = document.getElementById("main");

const phone = document.getElementById("phoneNumberInput").value;
const address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;

function checkingIsEmpty() {

  if (phone == ''){
    alert("Please insert your phone number");
    return false;
  } 
  if (address ==''){
    alert("Please insert your address");
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>checking form is empty</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="" action="index.html" method="post" onsubmit="return checkingIsEmpty()">
      <div id="message">
        <label>
          <textarea name="messageInput" rows="2" cols="40" placeholder="add message..."></textarea>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div id="phoneNumber">
        <input id="phoneNumberInput" type="number" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Please input your phonenumber">
      </div>
      <div id="address">
        <input id="addressInput" type="text" name="address" placeholder="your address here" size= "50px" value="" >
      </div>
      <div id="order">
        <input id="orderInput" type="submit" name="description" value="order" min='0'> <p></p>
      </div>
      <div id= "reset">
        <input type="reset" name="" value="RESET">
      </div>
    </form>

    <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for that. Just add `required` attribute on form inputs which are required. Let the browser do the work for you.

Comment: The problem you have is you check the value when the page loads. The string does NOT change as it is updated. You need to look at the value when you call the function.

Answer (score 2):

I'd agree with @Madara's comment, that you should... *just add `required` attribute on form inputs which are required and let the browser do the work for you*

However, I believe the reason your code is not working is because you appear to be setting the `const` values of `phone` and `address` on entry to the screen... and then you're checking that initial value (rather than the latest value).

Instead you need to get the latest value from the controls as part of the function...

```
function checkingIsEmpty(){
  if (document.getElementById("phoneNumberInput").value == ''){
    alert("Please insert your phone number");
    return false;
  } 
  if (document.getElementById("addressInput").value ==''){
    alert("Please insert your address");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

(Minor edit, you also need to `return true` at the end of your function, otherwise your submit won't work)

Comment: For a pure JavaScript approach, I like this solution also rather than using the required attribute.  Maybe if your app gets larger you might consider using a framework to do the heavy lifting.  The next step up is putting you values into an object and using something like requirejs.

Answer (score 0):

simplest way is to check `if (!phoneInput.value) { ... }`
as empty string and null will return falsy value

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is because you are assigning the value of the fields at the time the page *loads*. Not at the time the function is called on `submit`. If you move the variable assignment into the function it should work for you.

```js
const order = document.getElementById("orderInput");
const main = document.getElementById("main");





function checkingIsEmpty(){
  const phone = document.getElementById("phoneNumberInput").value;
  const address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;


  if (phone == ''){
    alert("Please insert your phone number");
    return false;
  } 
  if (address ==''){
    alert("Please insert your address");
    return false;
  }

  return false;//for the example I don't want it to submit
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>checking form is empty</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form class="" action="index.html" method="post" onsubmit="return checkingIsEmpty()">
          <div id="message">
            <label>
              <textarea name="messageInput" rows="2" cols="40" placeholder="add message..."></textarea>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div id="phoneNumber">
            <input id="phoneNumberInput" type="number" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Please input your phonenumber">
          </div>
          <div id="address">
            <input id="addressInput" type="text" name="address" placeholder="your address here" size= "50px" value="" >
          </div>
          <div id="order">
            <input id="orderInput" type="submit" name="description" value="order" min='0'> <p></p>
          </div>
          <div id= "reset">
            <input type="reset" name="" value="RESET">
          </div>
        </form>

        <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The values of inputs are stored inside a constant, not a variable.

When page is loaded, the script is executed and the contents of **actual** inputs are stored.

When you're calling `checkingIsEmpty()` the values aren't refreshed.

I suggest you to get the value inside the `checkingIsEmpty()` function if you want to keep checking with javascript, but as suggested Madara in comments, you can use the required attribute `<input id="phoneNumberInput" type="number" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Please input your phonenumber" required>`.

Checking inputs with required attribute or javascript is nice, but you have to check it **server-side** too. It's easy to press <kbd>F12</kbd> and edit dom.

```js
function checkingIsEmpty()
{
    let phone = document.getElementById("phoneNumberInput").value;
    let address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;

    if (phone == '')
    {
        alert("Please insert your phone number");
        return (false);
    } 
    if (address == '')
    {
        alert("Please insert your address");
        return (false);
    }
    return (true); //You forgot to return true in case of your form is validated
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>checking form is empty</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="" action="index.html" method="post" onsubmit="return checkingIsEmpty()">
            <div id="message">
                <label>
                    <textarea name="messageInput" rows="2" cols="40" placeholder="add message..."></textarea>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div id="phoneNumber">
                <input id="phoneNumberInput" type="number" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Please input your phonenumber">
            </div>
            <div id="address">
                <input id="addressInput" type="text" name="address" placeholder="your address here" size= "50px" value="" >
            </div>
            <div id="order">
                <input id="orderInput" type="submit" name="description" value="order" min='0'> <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id= "reset">
                <input type="reset" name="" value="RESET">
            </div>
        </form>

        <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the document.getElementById in your conditionals. Also, I would wrap both conditionals (Phone and Address) in another conditional so you can add classes for error styling on errored fields.

```js
const order = document.getElementById("orderInput");
const main = document.getElementById("main");

var phone = document.getElementById("phoneNumberInput").value;
var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;



function checkingIsEmpty(){
  if (document.getElementById("phoneNumberInput").value == '' || document.getElementById("addressInput").value == '') {
  if (document.getElementById("phoneNumberInput").value == ''){
   alert("Please insert your phone number");
   return false;
  } 
  if (document.getElementById("addressInput").value == ''){
   alert("Please insert your address");
   return false;
  }
 } else {
  alert('success');
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>checking form is empty</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form class="" action="index.html" method="post" onsubmit="return checkingIsEmpty()">
          <div id="message">
            <label>
              <textarea name="messageInput" rows="2" cols="40" placeholder="add message..."></textarea>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div id="phoneNumber">
            <input id="phoneNumberInput" type="number" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Please input your phonenumber">
          </div>
          <div id="address">
            <input id="addressInput" type="text" name="address" placeholder="your address here" size= "50px" value="" >
          </div>
          <div id="order">
            <input id="orderInput" type="submit" name="description" value="order" min='0'> <p></p>
          </div>
          <div id= "reset">
            <input type="reset" name="" value="RESET">
          </div>
        </form>

        <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

      </body>
    </html>
```